# How to store password as secure in database using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, security, passwords

I am storing the password as plain text in database in the following

[image: Basic form for getting user entered values]

[image: Add the entered values into database]

The following shows the output of the above code
[image: In a database the users tables containing the plain text password]

I know storing password as plain text in database as security threat. What are the best way to store as secured password format in a database? suppose we choose some algorithm to protect a password then what is the best algorithm is best to store password as secure in database?

Comment: SHA-256 is pretty decent

Comment: but using sha-256 is not safe I think, because using rainbow table attack the password may be guessable right.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: For php, use the functions `password_hash` and `password_verify` to do the job please

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: @SathiskumarS I have answer in detail. Try those functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PHP's password\_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords) . Don't be tempted to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

### Password Hashing

You can use **PHP [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function** for hashing the password with **multiple algorithms**. Here is an example:-

```
$password = "dskjfk111!";
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

You can provide different algorithms in second parameter. I used **PASSWORD_DEFAULT** which use **bcrypt algorithm**.

### Password Verification

The hashed password generated by password_hash() function has algorithm, salt and cost as part of the output (hashed password). So by using **[password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)** function, you can verify the password without providing algorithm used during hashing. Here is an example:-

```
$user_input = "dskjfk111!";
$result = password_verify($user_input);
if($result){
  echo "Password Valid"
}else{
  echo "Password Invalid"
}
```

### md5() or sha1()

**Don't use md5() or sha1() functions** for password. As you can read about it in [php.net documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash).